# MYSQL load data timestamp format

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load data into a MySQL table and all of my timestamps (datetime field type) are being loaded as null.  An example value I am trying to load is `"2002-04-26 19:31:15.200000000"` and I have specified the format as `'%Y-%c-%d %H:%i:%s.%f'` (statement below).

Since null is loading I am making an assumption that I have the format incorrect and that is causing the null to be loaded.  What is the correct format that I should be specifying?

```
set DateAdded = STR_TO_DATE(@DateAdded,'%Y-%c-%d %H:%i:%s.%f')
```

The complete `LOAD INFILE` statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'CANDIDATES.txt' INTO TABLE dbo.CANDIDATE 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
  ignore 1 lines 
  (ResumeKey,Address1,Address2,City,Candidate_Type,Candidate_Type_Changed_UserID,S‌​tate,Country,@DateAdded,@DateModified,Degree,Email,FirstName,GPA,GradYear,HomePho‌​ne,JobTitle,LastName,Locale,Major,MiddleName,OrgName,OtherPhone,SchoolName,Zip,Ac‌​tive_Flag,SecureCandidate_Flag,CandidateStackingField,CellPhone,Homepage,FaxNumbe‌​r,BRUID)
 set
   DateAdded = STR_TO_DATE(@DateAdded,'%Y-%c-%d %H:%i:%s.%f'),
   DateModified = STR_TO_DATE(@DateModified,'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s.%f');
```

Comment: Seems to work as expected. I get the correct value from `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2002-04-26 19:31:15.200000000', '%Y-%c-%d %H:%i:%s.%f');`  What does the rest of your `LOAD INFILE` statement look like? There may be another error.

Comment: Note - zero-padded months are probably better served by `%m` than `%c` but this should work either way.

Comment: Sure,the rest of the statement: LOAD DATA INFILE 'CANDIDATES.txt' INTO TABLE dbo.CANDIDATE FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
ignore 1 lines
(ResumeKey,Address1,Address2,City,Candidate_Type,Candidate_Type_Changed_UserID,State,Country,@DateAdded,@DateModified,Degree,Email,FirstName,GPA,GradYear,HomePhone,JobTitle,LastName,Locale,Major,MiddleName,OrgName,OtherPhone,SchoolName,Zip,Active_Flag,SecureCandidate_Flag,CandidateStackingField,CellPhone,Homepage,FaxNumber,BRUID)
set DateAdded = STR_TO_DATE(@DateAdded,'%Y-%c-%d %H:%i:%s.%f'),
DateModified = STR_TO_DATE(@DateModified,'%Y-%c-%e %H:%i:%s.%f')
;

Comment: Please edit the original post above to add the statement. You can highlight it and `ctl-k` or use the `{}` editor toolbar button to format it as a code block.

Comment: The `LOAD` statement looks correct to me. Please also post a sample of a few lines from the start of `CANDIDATES.txt`.

Comment: I copied some of the lines from my file to a sample to share here and the sample file loaded correctly.  I looked at the file encoding and noticed they were different.  The one that is not loading correctly is "text/plain; charset=utf-16le" and the one that loads perfectly is "text/plain; charset=us-ascii" .  What is the correct way to load a file encoded as utf-16le?  Should it be converted first?

Comment: This command fixed my problem "iconv -f utf-16le -t utf-8 CANDIDATES.txt > candidates2.txt"  I was able to load the file after that.

Comment: You should post your eventual solution as an answer below, then return and mark it accepted when the timeout has passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the file that was being loaded was not in utf-8 format.  MySQL can't load uff-16 files.

To convert the file on linux you would do this:iconv -f utf-16le -t utf-8 (file in uff-15le format) > (name of new uff-8 file)

if you need to find the current encoding of a file you can use file -ib filename.

After converting the file it loaded without issue.